# Laravel - How to validate fields from another tables in Request Rules

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel-5.8, I am trying to delevop a web application.I have two tables: goals and goal_details. Goal is the main model class.

Using Rules and Request in Laravel:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'goal_title'                => 'required|min:5|max:100',
        'goal_type_id'              => 'required',
        'weighted_score'            => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:500',           
        'start_date'                => 'required',
        'end_date'                  => 'required|after_or_equal:start_date',
        'kpi_description'           => 'required',
        'activity'                  => 'required',
    ];
}
```

goals: customer_id, goal_title, weighted_score, start_date, end_date

goal_details: goal_type_id, kpi_description

```
public function create()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id','appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();       
    $goaltypes   =       GoalType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
     $categories = GoalType::with('children')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->whereNull('parent_id')->get();

    return view('goals.create')
            ->with('goaltypes', $goaltypes)
            ->with('categories', $categories)
            ->with('identities', $identities);
}
public function store(StoreGoalRequest $request)
{
    $startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
    $endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $employeeId = Auth::user()->employee_id;
        $goal = new Goal();
        $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
        $goal->appraisal_identity_id    = $request->appraisal_identity_id;
        $goal->employee_id              = $employeeId;
        $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
        $goal->goal_title               = $request->goal_title;
        $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;
        $goal->start_date               = $startDate;
        $goal->end_date                 = $endDate;
        $goal->save();


        foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){
            $goaldetail = new GoalDetail();
            $goaldetail->kpi_description            = $request->kpi_description[$key];
            $goaldetail->activity                   = $request->activity[$key];
            $goaldetail->appraisal_goal_id          = $goal->id;
            $goaldetail->save();
         }

            Session::flash('success', 'Goal is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route('goals.index');
}
```

create.blade.php

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- general form elements -->
         <div class="card card-secondary">
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
          <form  method="POST" action="{{route('goals.store')}}">
          @csrf
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select id="goal_type" class="form-control" name="goal_type_id">
                <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                @unless($category->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                  <option disabled="disabled" value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                    @unless($child->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('category_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endunless
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                  @endunless
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>    
            
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Title:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="goal_title" placeholder="Enter goal title here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Goal Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="goal_description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Goal Description here ..."></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Activity<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">KPI Description<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">Attachment</th>
                            <th scope="col"><a class="addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi" ></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" name="appraisal_doc[]" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>


                    </table>
        </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Weight:</label>
              <input  type="number" name="weighted_score" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Start Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="start_date"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> End Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="end_date"  min="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')}}">
            </div>
          </div>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>           
       
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
   </div>
   <!--/.col (left) -->
  </div>
```

javascript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addRow').on('click', function () {
   var isHod = {{ Auth::user()->is_hod == 0 ? 0 : 1 }};
    var numRows = $('.activity').length

    if (isHod || (!isHod && numRows<3)) {
        addRow();
    }
        });

        function addRow() {
            var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
' <td><input type="text" name="activity[]" class="form-control activity" ></td>\n' +
'   <td><input type="text" name="kpi_description[]" class="form-control kpi_description" ></td>\n' +
' <td><div class="custom-file"><input type="file" name="appraisal_doc[]" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile"><label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label></div></td>\n' +
'  <td><a   class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>\n' +
'    </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(addRow);
            addRemoveListener();
        };
       addRemoveListener();
    });

function addRemoveListener() {
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
        var l =$('tbody tr').length;
        if(l==1){
            alert('you cant delete last one')
        }else{

            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        }

    });
  }

</script>
```

When I submitted, I observed that the fields from **goal_details: goal_type_id, kpi_description** are not validated as required. It allows null. But all fields in goals are validated.

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it can solve your "kpi_description" validation problem :

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'goal_title'                => 'required|min:5|max:100',
        'goal_type_id'              => 'required',
        'weighted_score'            => 'required|numeric|min:0|max:500',           
        'start_date'                => 'required',
        'end_date'                  => 'required|after_or_equal:start_date',
        'kpi_description'           => 'required|array',
        'kpi_description.*'         => 'required',
        'activity'                  => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after defining rules you have to call "validated" method as needed.
try this :

```
public function store(StoreGoalRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $startDate = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
    $endDate = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $employeeId = Auth::user()->employee_id;
        $goal = new Goal();
        $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
        $goal->appraisal_identity_id    = $request->appraisal_identity_id;
        $goal->employee_id              = $employeeId;
        $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
        $goal->goal_title               = $request->goal_title;
        $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;
        $goal->start_date               = $startDate;
        $goal->end_date                 = $endDate;
        $goal->save();


        foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){
            $goaldetail = new GoalDetail();
            $goaldetail->kpi_description            = $request->kpi_description[$key];
            $goaldetail->activity                   = $request->activity[$key];
            $goaldetail->appraisal_goal_id          = $goal->id;
            $goaldetail->save();
         }

            Session::flash('success', 'Goal is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route('goals.index');
}
```

Comment: if it didn't help let me see your form, please .

Comment: It didn't work. So I've added the form as requested. Thanks